# Simple algorithm without using built-in PHP functions?

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm meant to produce a simple algorithm, which I have, but I was asked to not use built-in PHP functions. Please help?

The main file looks like this (main.php):

```
<?php
    $myfile = "in.txt";
    $lines = file($myfile);
    $line1 = $lines[0];
    $line2 = $lines[1];
    $newtext = wordwrap($line2, $line1, "\n", false);
    $fh = fopen('out.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $newtext);
?>
```

And it is supposed to take a file (in.txt) which looks like this:

```
15 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi semper, est non gravida venenatis, est neque fringilla quam, hendrerit ultrices justo turpis nec augue.
```

And add the line breaks, with each line having X characters (is this case, 15)

The end product looks like this (out.txt):

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet,
consectetur
adipiscing
elit. Morbi
semper, est non
gravida
venetatis, est
negue fringilla
quam, hendrerit
ultrices justo
turpis nec
augue.
```

How could I go about creating this algorithm without using these premade PHP functions?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `fopen()`, `fwrite()` etc?

Comment: Did you try anything? Plus: School task. Do your homework yourself!

Comment: What is [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) (and some others you are using) but a php built-in function?

Comment: @will I think task is not to use `wordwrap`

Comment: @FirstOne Looks like just a school task where they need to write copy of `wordwrap`

Comment: ehh just look at php source code and copy what they did :S

Comment: @rjdown As an option write in in (python/js/c...) :)

Comment: What these homework-like questions fail to show is the possible path the algorithm should follow. Homeworks generally come for the purpose of practicing what's been learned (`for`, `if`, etc). Any answer for this would probably deviate from that purpose (besides, it generally stops the OP from actually practicing)

Comment: Well, I managed to create an algorithm that uses as little build-in function as I could. I'll post as an answer.. Check it out too @E_p ;)

Comment: "not use built-in PHP functions" so you cant use php at all then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = 15;
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi semper, est non gravida venenatis, est neque fringilla quam, hendrerit ultrices justo turpis nec augue.';
```

The simple solution would be to simply go through each character, keeping count of what character you are at, and then outputting a newline at the right place.

```
for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($text); $i < $l; $i++) {
    echo $text[$i];
    if ($i % $number === $number - 1) {
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Another way would be to figure out how many lines there will ultimately be and then extract the substrings accordingly, and again adding newlines at the right place:

```
$linesTotal = ceil(strlen($text) / $number);
for ($i = 0; $i < $linesTotal; $i++) {
    echo substr($text, $i * $number, $number);
    if ($i < $linesTotal - 1) {
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

This would be the better solution, but outside the parameters of the assignment:

```
echo trim(chunk_split($text, $number));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code I tried not to use functions like `strlen()`, `substr()` (or even `str_split()` / `array_splice()`). It turned out like this:

```
$qt = 15; // with how many chars to break the string
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi semper, est non gravida venenatis, est neque fringilla quam, hendrerit ultrices justo turpis nec augue.';

$result = '';
$c = 0;
$nl = '<br>'; // the break (could be /n, PHP_EOL, etc)

while(isset($text[$c])){ // avoid using built-in function to check string size
    $result .= $text[$c];
    $c++;
    if($c % $qt == 0){
        $result .= $nl;
    }
}

echo $result;
```

Output (with `<pre>` to show the quantity alingned):

```
Lorem ipsum dol
or sit amet, co
nsectetur adipi
scing elit. Mor
bi semper, est 
non gravida ven
enatis, est neq
ue fringilla qu
am, hendrerit u
ltrices justo t
urpis nec augue
.
```

See it in action [**here**](https://eval.in/605517).

---

---

I did this just to practice. You should try stuff on your on. People can't 'learn' logic for you.